# zip on grep on linux

Tags: linux, grep, zip

i have many txt files (>100) in dir. I want to zip all files which contain certain text in files. 
I had tried

```
for z in `grep -lr "some-string" .`
do 
  zip -g upload.zip $z; 
done
```

But it gives error as file name contains spaces.
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `$z` in quotes (i.e. `"$z"`)?

Comment: `grep -lZr "some-string" . | xargs -0 zip upload.zip`

Comment: @blender it is still giving error/warning `zip warning: upload.zip not found or empty` and `zip error: Nothing to do! (upload.zip)`

Comment: @vstm thanks it worked. will you explain `xargs` ?

Comment: @Netro: well in a nutshell: [xargs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs) reads parameters from stdin and appends it to the command given in the parameters of xargs so `echo hello world | xargs ls` becomes `ls hello world`. By default xargs uses "white space" to delimit the characters, like the shell would. With the `-0` argument you can tell it to delimit the parameters by zero-bytes (ascii 0) so the parameters can have spaces in them. Tools like grep and find have parameters too which tell them to output filenames delimited by zero-bytes.

Comment: I agree with all the answers, but I should remind you to **avoid spaces in filenames** in the first place (a lot of Unix utilities are unhappy with space in file paths, even if there is a way to handle them). Use underscores `_` in file paths instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The safest way to handle spaces, newlines and other weird characters in filenames, is to use the `-Z` option to ouput a zero byte between filenames in order to delimit them. You can then use `xargs` to pass the files to `zip`.

```
grep -lrZ "some-string" . | xargs -0 zip -g upload.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Never write

```
for file in <command>
```

as it cannot work for file names that contain spaces. If you need to loop on a list of file names output from some command, do it this way:

```
<command> |
while IFS= read -r file
```

It will still fail for file names that contains newlines but those are rare and should be fixed to not contain newlines.

So, instead of:

```
for z in `grep -lr "some-string" .`
do 
  zip -g upload.zip $z; 
done
```

you'd write :

```
grep -lr "some-string" . |
while IFS= read -r z
do 
  zip -g upload.zip "$z"
done
```

I also added quotes around $z. ALWAYS quote your shell variables unless you have a very good, explicit reason not to and fully understand all the consequences (which include failing on file names containing spaces and/or globbing characters).